# How to hide the tab close button [X] in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have done this before but unfortunately can't find the option in the VSCode settings now, neither I can find it by searching online. Can someone help me on how to switch off the little [X](for closing the tab), which appears on each tab when you hover over the tab?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set `workbench.editor.tabCloseButton` to `'off'`.

See [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_9#_new-setting-to-control-close-button-in-tabs).

Comment: To change the setting from the VSCode interface, press `CTRL + ,` to open the settings menu, and search for `tab close` in the search box. The setting is under `Workbench > Editor Management > Tab Close Button`. Set it to `off`.

Answer (score 0):

(in [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson))

#### For VS Code 1.85+

```json
"workbench.editor.tabActionCloseVisibility": false,

// you might also be interested in this for the unpin button:
// "workbench.editor.tabActionUnpinVisibility": false,
```

For the change history, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/196972.

#### For VS Code pre-1.85

```json
"workbench.editor.tabCloseButton": "off",
```